# Fitting Data in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, interpolation, data-fitting

I got a .txt file with x and y data set, which looks something like this:

```
310.5 ; 777.3
309.6 ; 769.3
308.9 ; 762.3
308.0 ; 759.3
307.2 ; 751.3
306.4 ; 744.3
```

I already splitted it up into a list of Double, so for example

```
MsgBox(xVal(0)) 
'310.5
```

and

```
MsgBox(yVal(0)) 
'777.3
```

The list has over 500 rows, so what I want to do is to fit the y Values like in a spline interpolation so I can easily calculate f(x) for any x in between. Is there any straightforward strategy?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any underlying physical phenomenon that would suggest what to fit the data to?

Comment: The dataset comes from a measurement taken over a mirror surface with high precision. It should be a smooth transition from point to point. Not sure if that was the answer you were looking for

Comment: To expand: if the measurement was of the position of an object accelerating under gravity, you might be looking to fit the data to a second-order polynomial; if the measurement was of the position of an object on a rotating disc then fitting to a sinusoid would be more appropriate. (I am not a data scientist.)

Comment: Take a look at [Linear and Cubic Spline Interpolation](https://codefying.com/2015/06/07/linear-and-cubic-spline-interpolation/) and [Spline interpolation](https://gist.github.com/dreikanter/3526685) if you don't mind c#.

Comment: Thank you both. I think I found what I was looking for. This PDF helped me a lot: https://charles-oneill.com/projects/cubicspline.pdf